# Prevent form reset after submit php

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamically populated table. Up on form submit I would like to keep the new values in the textfield of the form. After a search on Stack Overflow I found this

```
<form name="test" method="post">
Your Name: <input type="text" name="YourName" <?php if (isset($_POST['YourName'])) echo        'value="'.$_POST['YourName'].'"';?> >
```

I tried to adapt in to my form but was unable to do so. The textfield is still reset after button is clicked.

```
echo "<td width=40%><input type=text value='$location'"; 
if (isset($_POST['$dynamic_location'])) echo "value=".$_POST['$dynamic_location']; 
echo "name='$dynamic_location'></td>\n";
```

Comment: Is the page refreshing on send or are you sending the data with jquery?

Comment: I am sending to via php . is there a way to check if the page is refreshing ?

Comment: where is your form action?

Comment: If you're sending the page with the form itself, there isn't a way to stop it, using the submit button will send the request to what's specified in the action tag as form data. One way to get around it is using jquery/ javascript to prevent this action but you then have to mimic the behaviour

Comment: i have not implemented any form action yet

Comment: @Bankzilla However , the first example case work on my page. Is there a reason why it doesnt not on my form ?

Comment: If you're sending the data to same page and are catching it somewhere. Then specify the action, `action="#"`.

Comment: yes i have specified action'#' on my form. can i prevent the page from refreshing ?

Comment: prevent the refresh with `document.forms[0].onsubmit = function (event) { event.preventDefault(); };` and send the data manually by serializing it with `document.forms[0].serialize()` using AJAX.  If you do this, you may as well change the button from a submit button to just a `button` type to avoid stopping the submit action all together.

Answer (score 0):

For the new values to keep up in the fields you how to add another query to fetch the data from the database and echo it in its individual fields.

And remember to fetch only the fields needed that will increase your execution time.

Answer (score 0):

If `action=""` or not set at all, following should work

```
if (isset($_POST['$dynamic_location'])) echo "value=".$_POST['$dynamic_location']; 
echo "name='$dynamic_location'/>";
```

If `action="another_file.php"` , you can do this
In another_file.php

```
header("location:previous_page.php?dynamic_location=".$_POST['$dynamic_location']);
```

On current file or previous_page.php

```
if (isset($_GET['dynamic_location'])) echo "value=".$_GET['dynamic_location']; 
echo "name='$dynamic_location'/>";
```